# Gson is adding slashes to my JSON strings

Tags: java, gson

I have a Java map like this:

```java
HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
map.put("someKey", jsonStringVariable);
map.put("someOtherKey", jsonStringVariable2);
```

where `jsonStringVariable` and `jsonStringvariable2` are strings with valid JSON.

Ultimately, I want to use Gson to make the entire map a single JSON string, currently doing it like this:

```
Gson gson = new Gson();
String json = gson.toJson(map);
```

However, now `json` has added a lot of backslashes to the original JSON strings in the map. How can I prevent Gson from adding slashes to my original JSON variables and just keep them as JSON?

Comment: Unmarshal the two JSON strings, add the result to the map, and serialize the map.

Comment: You're putting one JSON document in another (as text). Rather combine them to a single document.

Answer (score 1):

I found a solution that works myself, by converting the JSON string to an object first, then later converting it back into a string:

```java
HashMap<String, Object> map = new HashMap<String, Object>();
map.put("someKey", gson.fromJson(jsonStringVariable, Object.class);
map.put("someOtherKey", gson.fromJson(jsonStringVariable2, Object.class);
```

I'm not sure if this is efficient, but at least for now it works. If anyone knows a more efficient method, please let me know!

Comment: yeah that i have also tried.. works fine. as at the end u need to provide the object to Gson rather the String..

Answer (score 1):

This is because strings must be encoded and properly escaped where necessarily in order to keep the result JSON document syntactically correct.

> I'm not sure if this is efficient, but at least for now it works. If anyone knows a more efficient method, please let me know!

The weak points of your `gson.fromJson`-based solution may:

- ... be relatively not very cheap itself (looking up a type adapter, Java reflection, etc);
- ... pick up not an uexpected type adapter behind the scenes when treating everything as `Object.class`;
- ... consume (much) more memory to hold deserialized values that are supposed just to be written back;
- ... return output JSON representations that do not match the input JSON representations.

You might what to use `JsonWriter` in such case:

```java
final Writer writer = new StringWriter();
// ...
try ( final JsonWriter jsonWriter = new JsonWriter(writer) ) {
    jsonWriter.beginObject();
    jsonWriter.name("someKey");
    jsonWriter.jsonValue(someValue);
    jsonWriter.name("someOtherKey");
    jsonWriter.jsonValue(someOtherValue);
    jsonWriter.endObject();
}
// ...
return writer.toString();
```

Note that you not necessarily have to use `StringWriter`: you can "redirect" the combined output to any `Writer` instance.
So using it like that you get:

- not using `Gson` at all;
- defining JSON structure regardless `Gson` instance configuration;
- consuming minimum memory;
- making sure that the values are written as-is.

For example, if you have `someValue` and `someOtherValue` like these:

```
[
    "foo", "bar"
]
```

```
{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2
}
```

the output becomes as follows:

```
{"someKey":[
    "foo", "bar"
]
,"someOtherKey":{
    "foo": 1,
    "bar": 2
}
}
```

If you need the values to be normalized (without whitespaces, new lines, etc), you just have to read every JSON value via `JsonReader` and just delegate its incoming results to the `JsonWriter` instance reflectively (got `BEGIN_OBJECT`? - write using `.beginObject`, etc).